# IIS URL Rewrite module repeats query string

Tags: url-rewrite-module

I have this rule, to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectToHttps" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I found it on the Internet.

It works fine for simple URLs without query strings. But it duplicates query strings. For example `http://example.com/path?key=value` becomes `https://example.com/path?key=value&key=value`.

This causes problems in debugging and troubleshooting. What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 16):

Problem is that variable `REQUEST_URI` contains URL and query string. In your case you have two solutions:

1) Add attribute `appendQueryString="false"` to your action. Rule should be like that:

.

```
<rule name="RedirectToHttps" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" negate="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

2) Instead `REQUEST_URI` you can use `URL` variable because this variable contains only URL without the query string. The rule should be like that:

.

```
<rule name="RedirectToHttps" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" negate="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{URL}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that I think the official MS docs on this page are wrong: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables 

It states that `REQUEST_URI` is "The path-absolute part of the URI.
For example `https://contoso.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret` would return `/over/there`"

This answer is correct. `REQUEST_URI` contains the querystring.